# How to catch php message return value and show it by java script alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using HTML5 form validation and and wana to change custom validation error to user, but i found a function that works on javascript, my problem is that my consol give me some tip, it said TypeError: $(...).setCustomValidity is not a function, i know that it,s java scripts function, so what should i use in jquery???
is there any same function??

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    //the min chars for username  

    //when field is focus out  
    $('#phone').focusout(function(){  
        //run the character number check  
            //get the phone  
     $phone = $('#phone').val();


    //use ajax to run the check  
      $.ajax({

            url: 'check.php',
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'html',
                data: { 
                        phone : $('#phone').val()

                        },
            success:function(response){
                if(response == "1"){

                    $('#phone').setCustomValidity('blahblahbla ');
                }
             }
                });
```

});

here is my code, thanks for your answers.

Comment: what was the question again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("phone").setCustomValidity("My Message Here");
```

instead, although I am not sure that will accomplish what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/FftM3/

Comment: oh my god:((((((((((((( your a goddamn! i confuse with this problem about 8 hour, thanks man :*